# Issue with multiple wildcard symbols when iterating in array with `.gsub!`

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, gsub, string-substitution

I am trying to figure out how to replace multiple characters in an array of strings by using multiple wildcards (or some other method if someone knows better.)  Each element in the array is a telephone number and date,  (ex. 8675309,2015-01-20).  I am trying to remove the comma and date only so that each element in the array be the telephone number only

When iterating over each element in the array, I obtained expected results by calling `.gsub!` when replacing a single character each element.

```
file_data = ["8675309,2015-01-20"]
puts file_data[0] #=> 8675309,2015-01-20
file_data.each do |s|
    s.gsub!(/0/, "X")
end
puts file_data[0] #> 86753X9,2X15-X1-2X
```

To eliminate the comma and date, I tried simply using wildcards, calling `s.gsub!(",****/**/**", "")`.  Then, this shows unexpected results:

```
file_data = ["8675309,2015-01-20"]
file_data.each do |s|
    s.gsub!(/,****-**-**/, "")
end
puts file_data[0] #> 8675309,2015-01-20
```

I also tried several other wildcard characters that have been suggested in other threads ('.*' and '^*'), but the results have not changed.

I am lost on how to eliminate the comma and date in each element while leaving the primary number intact. I thought `.gsub!` would be the proper method, but am open to any alternatives as well.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I might use `String#split` to get the phone number:

```
file_data = ["8675309,2015-01-20"]
phone_numbers = file_data.map {|s| s.split(',').first }
phone_numbers[0] #=> "8675309"
```

Or, if the phone number is always 7 characters, I might get a string subset with `[]`:

```
file_data.map {|s| s[0,7] }
```

Or, if you really want to stick with a regular expression:

```
file_data.each do |s|
  s.gsub!(/,.*\z/, '')
end
```

Which reads as: part of a string starting from the first comma to the end of the string, replace with nothing.

Comment: `s[0..6]` is quicker than `map {|s| s[0,7] }`

Answer (score 1):

The way you are handling wildcards is excessive. Why are you using wildcards when you know what you want to sub? Removing commas and the date (as long as the date is always the same format) should be simple:

```
name = "8675309,2015-01-20"
name.gsub!(/,\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#partition`

```
name.partition(',')[0]

=>"8675309"
```